# mongoengine datetime field and python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, tornado, mongoengine

I am facing the following issue which I didnt came across in my other application.

My Sprint datamodel:

```
import mongoengine as me

class Sprint(me.Document):
    start_date = me.DateTimeField(),
    end_date = me.DateTimeField(),
    sequence = me.IntField(required=True, default=0)
```

In shell I tried following:

```
sprint = Sprint.objects.get(sequence=1)
sprint
<Sprint: Sprint object>

sprint.start_date - datetime.utcnow()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

then I printed sprint.start_date
it returned a tuple instead of datetime object as follows:

```
sprint.start_date
(<mongoengine.fields.DateTimeField object at 0x22b7dd0>,)
```

So I did

```
sprint.start_date[0] - datetime.utcnow()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DateTimeField' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I didn't get this issue any of my earlier project. My current mongoengine version is 0.6.20. I didn't upgarded it for my current project and has been using this for all of my projects.
 I am using tornado as the web server

How to convert mongoengine datetime field to compatible to python datetime instance.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Something is very wrong here: 
sprint = Sprint.objects.get(sequence=1) should be returning a single object not a queryset.  Again getting an attribute should return the value not the field.  Can you check your version and installation, if its also broken in the shell then you can rule out tornado being an issue.

Comment: Hi Ross,
Yes thats my fault of writing it as a queryset. I apologise for that and will edit it. Rest is correct my mongoengine version is 0.6.20. Yesterday, I even downgraded it to 0.6.7 which is working fine on my peers system, but still I am getting same error and yet unresolved. :(

Comment: I would use ipdb and trace the error, make sure you have the correct mongoengine installed and no other versions on your system.  Also what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the datamodel definition itself. A type caused all these. :(

start_date and end_date have a ',' in the end which is creating the noise.

After removing it, it rolls. :)

Comment: You may accept your own answer, or event delete the question as it is not likely to be helpful to anyone.